# How to download data from stocktwits,just like:symbol： "SPX", in the whole 2017？

Tags: api, download, stocktwits

My reasearch need data posted from Stocktwits,Just like search :the symbol "SPX",and download microblogging messages of S&P 500 Index posted between October 2016 and October 2017.
The target page:https://stocktwits.com/symbol/SPX.
How can I download the full text?

Answer (score 0):

The API does not allow querying by date. Please see the API docs on how to request streams for symbols here

https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#streams-symbol-docs

and how to paginate through the streams

https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/parameters

Comment: Tranks for your help~.The API docs has said：The API methods   access a theoretical maximum of 800 messages，but some paper from SCI had showed that they can get the whole time messages from API，how can they achieve it？ Some from the paper: all messages are available through the Web site’s application programming
interface (API). The analyzed period comprises
from January 1, 2013 to August 31, 2015. During
this period, 90.786 stock-related microblogging messages
holding the dollar-tagged ticker symbol of S&P
500 index were collected.

Comment: @hunterlzl they likely have a partnership with StockTwits, which is usually made with educational programs for research purposes. You can achieve this through the api by paginating with respect to the rate limit or you can request to be a partner. Please note everything you need is in the developer portal. https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs